# How to change default operator in solr velocity?

Tags: solr, velocity

in solr schema the defaultOperator value is OR but when i use browse(http://localhost:8983/solr/browse)for searching AND is a defaultOperator,how can i change the velocity template engine default operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dismax uses minimum match (`mm`) to check the number of terms needed for the document to be matched.

[The default value of mm is 100%](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) (meaning that all clauses must match).

`q.op` doesn't override the `mm` value for the dismax parser.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1889

Try mm set to 0% to emulate the OR behavior -

```
<str name="mm">0%</str>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the defaultOperator by adding the following entry to the `<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">` section of the solrconfig.xml file.

```
<str name="q.op">OR</str>
```

For more information on the `q.op` parameter, please see the [Solr SearchHandler Wiki Page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#q.op)